# JQuery SlideUP and SlideDown based on Selector Help

Tags: jquery, menu, selector, slidedown, slideup

I'm teaching myself jQuery and having fun trying to figure this out. I'm using the `slideDown` and `slideUp` functions to have different `<div>`'s appear and disappear if needed. But my problem is in the removal. I can get the different selected options to appear separately, however, if both `<div>`'s are showing when I try to remove just one of the `<div>`'s, both `<div>`'s flash quickly and then both disappear. It also happens when only one of the `<div>`'s is showing too. I click the remove link and both `<div>`'s flash quickly and then disappear. I really haven't got a clue as to why. The idea behind this code is to allow a user to add to and take away as needed. If a selection was made in mistake, the user would be able to remove it while the other selections that were previously selected stay visible. Here's my code:

```
<div class="type-select" style="width:400px;">
<select name="selectStatus">
<option selected value="Select">Select...</option>
<option id="login">Login</option>
<option id="nav">Navigation</option>
</select></div>
<div id="loginselect"><img src="http://triplemsystems.ekkosolutions.com/images/global/bg-loginPages.gif" height="47" width="162" />
<a id="remove" href="">Remove</a></div>
<div id="navselect"><img src="http://triplemsystems.ekkosolutions.com/images/global/bg-navMain.gif" height="45" width="90"/>
<a id="removenav" href="">Remove</a></div>
<script>
$("#loginselect").hide("fast");
$("select").change(function(){
    if($("#login").is(":selected")){ 
        $("#loginselect").slideDown("slow");}
});
$("#remove").click(function() {
    $("#loginselect").slideUp("slow");
});

$("#navselect").hide("fast");
$("select").change(function () {
    if($("#nav").is(":selected")){
        $("#navselect").slideDown("slow");}
});

$("#removenav").click(function() {
    $("#navselect").slideUp("slow");});

</script>
```

Am I even on the right path?

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood your question, it works fine for me (in Chrome - what browser are you experiencing the issue in?): http://jsfiddle.net/55NCM/1/

Comment: @James Allardice I'm using Firefox 5.

Comment: @James: The code in the fiddle is not identical to the code in the OP.

Comment: See @Andrew Whitaker's answer, I think he's right. I added `javascript:void(0)` to the `href` attributes of your links in the fiddle I posted, which has pretty much the same effect. Also note that you can condense your `$("select").change` functions into one (again, see my fiddle).

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - Yeah, I added the `javascript:void(0)` to the links without even considering that that was what could be causing the problem! I just did it because jsfiddle throws an error when you click a link with an empty `href`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path, I *think* the problem is that you are not preventing the default action of the links, and so the page is being refreshed (causing you to see the `div`s for a second). You can prevent the default action of a link by accepting an `event` parameter and calling `.preventDefault()` on it, i.e:

```
$("#remove").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#loginselect").slideUp("slow");
});
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/XzDzb/

Comment: Stop misusing return false!
http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: That's exactly what was going on. Thanks for the help.